# can't capture boto3 using python placebo

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, ptpython

I have some Python (v.3.x) that works like a charm on AWS using boto3 etc..
Now I'm asked to write some tests around that, so I found this to capture the response which I'll create the test around it:

https://github.com/garnaat/placebo

Using ptpython I'm able to run my code, but the recording is not happening (not that I can find), here's what I did:

```
session = boto3.Session()
pill = placebo.attach(session, data_path='/c/Users/myuser/placebo')
pill.record()
run my python code which does the job
```

The only thing I'm thinking right now is the fact I'm on Windows 7, maybe it's not accepting the path.
Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried constructing your path with either `os.path.join` or [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)?

Comment: yes I did, the result is still the same, I'm keeping it super simple at this point but it's not working.
I had a friend try to run it as well, again same result i.e. not working (only diff between us is he has windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, this step is not included in the documentation above I found it elsewhere:

```
session = boto3.Session()
pill = placebo.attach(session, data_path='.')
pill.record()
ec2 = session.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
response = ec2.describe_instances()
```

that got me a recording, from here I can do whatever boto3 code I want - hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to mock the access credentials during playback?

Comment: sorry for the late response I was away, can you share what you're doing and what's not working?